# Return date 260 working days from reference date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a daily data dataframe (`df`) indexed by date - the head is below:

```
                  nominal  
date                                                                          
2016-01-04      114185.481138            
2016-01-04       17841.990960            
2016-01-04       -8799.514730          
2016-01-04           0.000000                 
2016-01-04       -3028.765682
```

I can find the max date using

```
maxDate = df.index.max()
```

How would I find the date 260 working days (1 working year) before this date? How could I go about retrieving the date 260 days ago from the maxDate?

Comment: This is a good reference: [datetime timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `Bday`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
df.index.max()-BDay(260)

Timestamp('2015-01-05 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
#Only use the following line if the column type for your 'date' column is
# string
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
(max(df['date']) - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(260)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#The line above produces:
# '2015-01-06'
```

Comment: Which is incorrect, because OP wants "business days" only.

Comment: Nice, thanks for changing your answer. Unfortunately, it's identical to Wen's ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understanding you wanting to subtract a date, in your case it would be like this:
    import datetime
    dat = datetime.datetie(2016,1,4)
    dd = datetime.timedelta(days = 260)
    print(dat - dd)

output: 2015-04-19

Comment: No, you understood wrong. Op wants _business days_. See the answer with 2 upvotes and compare.